# Google API keywords list

Tags: c#, google-api, oauth-2.0

### In Google OAuth 2.0 Then have given Following details to call UserInfo API.

Calling a Google API

After your application has obtained an access token, your application can access a Google API by including it in either an access_token query parameter or an Authorization: Bearer HTTP header.

For example, a call to the UserInfo API using the access_token query string parameter looks like the following:

### GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?access_token=432563532432545436

Here userinfo is a keyword used to userinfo API.  I want other API's keyword. Anybody knows?

Comment: Pick which one you want https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/

Comment: I need for
https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom

Comment: You mean Google Reader?

Comment: Nope. Please browse mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom 
you wil get an idea. This just reads inbox of gmail

Comment: That link takes me to Google Reader (ask me to subscribe to some not existing feed), or ask me for a username and password if I'm not logged on.

Comment: Yes. After login You wil get an XML code with inbox unread mail details

Comment: I cannot login and I cannot subscribe to the feed. Can't help you anymore.

Comment: What do you need? OAuth's API information? Gmail API? What are you looking to achieve in the end?